# On accept-reject method for unknown function

Tags: self-study, algorithms, rejection-sampling

My problem is this I have a posterior as $Gamma(\alpha, \beta) \times exp(\lambda)$.

$$Y_{1}^{n} \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$$
$$\alpha \sim Exp(\lambda)$$
$$\beta \sim Exp(\lambda)$$
Now $n=50, \alpha=7, \beta=9$.

$$P(\alpha,\beta|Y)\propto (\prod_{i=1}^{n}{y_{i}^{\alpha-1}}){{\beta^{n\alpha}}\over{\Gamma(\alpha)^{n}}}
\lambda^{2}e^{-(\lambda\alpha+\lambda\beta+\beta\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_{i}})}$$

So I have it in a metropolis algorithm to get samples.

But now I need to apply the accept-reject method to the parameter $\alpha$ while $\beta$ is can do it with the full conditional that is a gamma($n\alpha+1, \lambda+\sum{y_{i}}$).
The conditional for alpha is this:

$$P(\alpha|\beta, y)=\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{n}{y_{i}^{\alpha-1}}){\beta^{n\alpha}}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^{n}} e^{-\lambda\alpha}$$

And I really can't find a function that cover that one, I have tried a gamma(), exp(), unif(), but nothing, and it gets very step quite fast, any suggestions to the accept-reject method?

[previous problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126279/problem-expressing-full-conditionals)

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Have you tried the Stirling approximation to the Gamma function: [$$\ln(\Gamma(z)) \approx \tfrac{1}{2} \left[\ln(2 \pi) - \ln(z) \right] + z \left[\ln \left( z + \frac{1}{12z- \frac{1}{10z}} \right)-1\right]$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: Actually, you could rephrase your target as being $$f(\alpha|\eta,n)\propto \eta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)^{-n}$$

Comment: How so, can I just throw the $\prod$ and the e, how and why? The main problem is the $\beta^{na}$ as it grows fast not even taking log shows some improvement

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso I improved formatting of your question, check if everything is ok. Also review the changes in the source code to check how could you use Tex to get nicely-formatted equations. Consider also reading the [formatting guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn using the markdown.

Comment: @Tim, Hey you miss the $y_{i}$'s in the product and the division is outside the parenthesis, everything else looks cool, thanks.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso I think it would be better if you edited it so it would be correct.